# Accessing variable, stored in package's init from file in package

Tags: python, importerror

I have a package named `pkg` and array named `arr` in `__init__` file of this package.
Also, I have file `file.py` in this package where I write `from pkg import arr` but it throws `ImportError`. How to import array properly?

Tree would look like this

```
pkg
- file.py
- __init__.py
```

`__init__.py`

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`file.py`

```
from pkg import arr # ImportError raises here

print (arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__.py` defines how your package looks from outside.

Try importing like this `from . import arr`, this basically means from current module import `arr`.

When asking about an error you should also provide the error message, `ImportError` is not enough. It could be a circular-import related error or a missing-library kind of error. The message usually helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the list `arr` in this manner. The file `file.py` should be in the base directory not in the package.

Hence the tree should be:

```
base
  - pkg   
    - __init__.py
  - file.py
```

Or, if you want to access the list from inside the package the import statement should be as the following:

```
from __init__ import arr
```

Comment: It can absolutely be in the same directory, you just have to watch out for circular imports.